# filtering data after fetch for graph

Tags: reactjs, fetch, fetch-api

I am fetching data from the database using API and the data will be used to show in the graph. below is the format of the API. I would like my graph to show just the time alone and not the date with the timezone. And is there a way to change the value from string to int?

```
API data
[{"time":"2022-01-13T15:26:20.129055+08:00","location":"north","value":"30","sensorType":null,"type":"temperature"},
{"time":"2022-01-13T15:54:31.718588+08:00","location":"north","value":"35","sensorType":null,"type":"temperature"}]
```

```
code for fetch and x,y for plotting graph
 const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    asyncFetch();
  }, []);

  const asyncFetch = () => {
      fetch('api')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('fetch data failed', error);
      });
  };
    const config = {
        data,
        xField: 'time',
        yField: 'value',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `Date` object from the time string and get the time as you need.

Try like below.

```js
const apiData = {"time":"2022-01-13T15:26:20.129055+08:00","location":"north","value":"30","sensorType":null,"type":"temperature"};

const timeStamp = new Date(apiData.time);
 
// int value of time in millis
console.log(timeStamp.getTime());

// formatted time
console.log(`${timeStamp.getHours()}:${timeStamp.getMinutes()}`);
```

In your then block update the data before setting it to `data`.

```
.then((json) =>
    setData(
        (json || []).map((item) => {
            const timeStamp = new Date(item.time);
            return {
                ...item,
                time: `${timeStamp.getHours()}:${timeStamp.getMinutes()}`,
            };
        })
    )
)
```

Comment: issit possible to change it on the data variable before the config ?

Comment: Yes, I will update the answer !

Comment: @JJJJJ, updated the answer! can you please mark this as the answer after you validate it?

Comment: i had this typeerror: data.filter is not a function. could this error be on the modules that im using ?

Comment: can you put a console.log(json) and update the question with it?

Comment: where do i put the console.log ? never really use console.log for debugging before. it might be the data from that i grab from the api is an object

Comment: i updated my api data

Comment: It's an array I was thinking its an object! updated the answer

Comment: oh thank you! but the value of the time seems to be weird. I got 1642423169392 for the value of the time

Comment: my initial thoughts for the time would  the 15:26 from the API. i guess the getTime() function was in millisecond

Comment: I can't see what package you are using to draw the grapth. I have seen some (react-google-charts) support Date object and show timely data nicely.

Comment: thanks for the help ! the time is correct ! had stuck at this part for days. I am currently using ant design chart for my graph.